# What is an example of a language with a "per-object" method?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, language-agnostic

I am reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) guide. It says that the following example shows that there are no "per object" methods in javascript:

```
function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.gender = '';

Person.prototype.sayGender = function () {
  alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;

person1.sayGender(); // alerts 'Male'
genderTeller(); // alerts undefined
alert(genderTeller === person1.sayGender); // alerts true
alert(genderTeller === Person.prototype.sayGender); // alerts true
```

The guide explains that Javascript has no "per object" methods because `genderTeller()` and the `sayGender()` method on person1 each point back to the same method in the prototype.

I am most familiar with languages like C# and Java, where individual objects inherit from classes. I don't know too much about how those languages work under the hood -- but in these cases it would seem like there are no "per-object" methods. Individual objects have methods that come from the class -- although I suppose they could override the super class method. Is that what the article means by "per-object" methods? Is that a common CS term?

Answer (score 2):

The article is pointing out that it is possible in JavaScript to call an object's method without using the object context. Another way to say this is that when JavaScript executes this code:

```
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;
```

...it stores a reference to the function `sayGender`, but there is no reference to person1. So if you execute `genderTeller` it will run `sayGender`, but `this` will not be a reference to a `Person` object. So the reference to `this.gender` would be undefined.

Generally, this is not what you want to happen, but it is possible.

Now you might be asking "WHY? Why would the language let you do this?" Well, actually, there are a few reason, but I'll just give you a simple one: in JavaScript you can exploit this feature and write code like this:

```
genderTeller.call(person1); // alerts 'Male'
```

In fact, you can use any object that has a `gender` property:

```
var android = { gender: "neuter" };
genderTeller.call(android); // alerts 'neuter'
```

Try it and see. Look at the documentation for the `call()` method of `Function` (with a capital F) to learn how this works.

Now this type of coding is probably not going to be tolerated on large projects because it breaks encapsulation. If someone adds code to `sayGender` that uses some new property of `Person`, then our little `android` object won't have that property and the function call may not behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend here. [This article on Ruby](http://www.wobblini.net/singletons.html) explains per object pretty well IMO.

From the article:

```
str = "I am a string"
def str.negate
  puts "It is not true that " + self
end
```

> > At this point, the object str and ONLY the object str has access to that method. This is called a singleton method.
> >
> > This is a very "prototype"-style thing: **the object parts company with the class that defined it, and now behaves in a way that is unique to it. Another instance of String won't have a "negate" method.**

Answer (score 0):

If you know oop language like c#' java , then you will have some confusion trying to compare them!

C# and javascript are both OOP BUT,
C# is class based oop while javascript is prototypal OOP

In c# class is basic block that create the objects ,,

In javascript function is the basic block that create the objects (which are also sunctions)
Also in javascript the functions is an object in itself!!!

Confusing ,,,right?

My purpose is to make u realise that it is better to forget what you know about c# and not try to compare both till you grasp the concept of function, prorotype, closure etc

I hope that help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to say that JavaScript doesn't have *bound* methods.  That is, there's no such thing as a method that remembers what object it belongs to before you call it.

In your example, `genderTeller` doesn't work because it's just the function; `person1` isn't attached to it at all.

But compare with this Python code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, gender):
        self.gender = gender

    def say_gender(self):
        print(self.gender)

person1 = Person('other')
person1.say_gender()  # prints "other"
gender_teller = person1.say_gender
gender_teller()  # prints "other"

print(gender_teller == person1.say_gender)  # false!
print(gender_teller == Person.say_gender)  # also false!
```

In Python, "getting" a method from an object (as `person1.say_gender` does) produces a bound method object, which remembers *both* the object it was produced from (`person1`) and the underlying function (`Person.say_gender`).  Most of the time the object is called immediately, but you can also pass bound methods around or store them or do whatever you want, since they're just objects like any other.

This is one of the things I feel makes Python especially consistent in a nice way; everything you use `()` is just an object.  There's no special syntax for a special kind of call.  In JavaScript, `object.method()` does something completely different from `object.method`.

As for other languages, hmm.

Ruby has bound method, but just doing `obj.method` without parentheses calls the method anyway, so you have to do something special to get a bound method object.

Perl has the same problem of calling implicitly when you do `$obj->method`, and doesn't have bound methods at all.

C# apparently has bound methods in exactly the same way as Python, according to this question: [Does C# support Bound Method or Method Closure (Special Closure which allows this to always point to instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482483/does-c-sharp-support-bound-method-or-method-closure-special-closure-which-allow)

Off the top of my head I'm not sure about any others, but I think "bound method" is a pretty common term if you want to look for more.